# Magento 2 product import not working showing error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.6

Maximum error count has been reached or system error is occurred!

Following Error(s) has been occurred during importing process:
Only the first 100 errors are shown.

```
General system exception happened
Additional data:

Notice: Undefined index: "SKU NAME" in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php on line 1905
```

Can any one help me to solve this error or debug this error why this error is showing.while updating product useing csv fiel.

Comment: can you check product sku attribute name and in your csv name of sku column is same??

Comment: yes it's same even i am geting this error.

Comment: this is because your CSV files have errors. Try exporting the CSV files again, Let me know if this helps

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your CSV file?